# css min-width and max-width?

Tags: width, css

```
.post-body p img {
    min-width:100%;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
.post-body p img.thumb-small {
    min-width:auto !important;
    max-width:100%;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}
```

i want all my images inside of post-body p to be min-width 100%. However if the image has a class of thumb-small there should be NO min-width?
how can i reverse that behaviour for images with this class?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can i reverse that behaviour for
>   images with this class?

```
.post-body p img.thumb-small {
    min-width:0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just specify a `min-width` of zero for the thumbnails:

```
.post-body p img.thumb-small {
    min-width: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

You don't need the `!important`. The style rule is more specific, so it will take precedence anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't checked it, but

```
min-width: 0;
```

should work, no need for !important, you are already overriding the rule with the added class.

Answer (score 1):

`min-width: inherit`